# How to shuffle the order of items when using ConcatAdapter?

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I'm going to use two types of views in the `recyclerview`.

Each item can be added or deleted.

Rather than checking the ViewType using a single Adapter, I know that it is a `ConcatAdapter` and try to use it.

By the way, is there a way to arrange the order the way I want when using `ConcatAdapter`?

As mentioned, the order is not consistent, as items can be added and deleted between each item.

The `ConcatAdapter` in the code I found was only able to find a way to list items in `A` and then list items in `B`.

**ex)**

> AAAAA BBBBBB

**what I want**

> ABABBBABBBABBBBBBBA

**The code I studied...**

```
val A_Items = ArrayList<RoutineModel>()
A_Items.add(aModel("e","eqw","ewqe"))
A_Items.add(aModel("e","eqw","ewqe"))
A_Items.add(aModel("e","eqw","ewqe"))

val B_Items = arrayListOf<bModel>()
B_Items.add(bModel())
B_Items.add(bModel())
B_Items.add(bModel())
B_Items.add(bModel())

A_adapter = AAdapter(A_Items)
B_adapter = BAdapter(B_Items)
concatAdapter = ConcatAdapter(A_adapter, B_adapter)
```

Comment: `ConcatAdapter` is not made for this, its only purpose is to combine adapters sequentially. You have to use view types here.

Comment: Concatenation (in programming at least) usually means adding one thing to the end of another thing - so in this case, all your stuff in the A adapter, then all the B's

Comment: It seems you better try another approach, instead shuffle the item in the `ConcatAdapter` (which not made for handling shuffling)`, I think you should shuffle the item in your list object

Comment: @PutraNugraha 
So should I not use ConcatApdater at all in my case?
How about [this link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GIow64uY7ow) and [this link](https://github.com/OHoussein/Android-Expandable-ConcatAdapter)?

Comment: @cactustictacs So is ConcatAdapter not appropriate in my case?

Comment: If you want to interleave items, then no. ``ConcatAdapter`` is basically for putting two lists in the same ``RecyclerView``, one after the other. You seem to want to display a single list, that has two different types of item, which means one adapter handling different view types, like you were trying to avoid. Sorry!

Comment: link you provide is expandable recycler view, seems not relate with your case. I think you can instead use single list, by adjusting your list if you expect to shuffle it

Comment: @PutraNugraha 
So you mean it looks better to use a single Adapter with a shuffled list than a ConcatAdapter to differentiate ViewTypes?